# Understanding the null conditional operator

Tags: c#

I am reading [this](https://csharp.today/c-6-features-null-conditional-and-and-null-coalescing-operators/) article and it has this example

```
int? length = people?.Length; // null if people is null
```

My question is if the first question mark after the `int` a typo ? If not what is the purpose of introducing a `?` after an int. I understand why its introduced after people. The reason for that is if `people` is `null` then it will return a `null`. Can someone explain the purpose of the `?`

Comment: `int?` is equivalent to `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: That turns `int` into a nullable int. Otherwise you can't assign an int to null.

Comment: @Amy can you put that down as anwser

Comment: @MistyD No, your question is a duplicate of the question indicated above your question.